# QuickAction Dialog in iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, quickaction

Is there are anyway to create quickAction dialog for iPhone exactly like whats in android?

How anyone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share quickAction dialog picture for android.

Comment: http://www.google.com.eg/imgres?sa=X&espvd=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=1MJmtCtmwsZa1M%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.londatiga.net%2Fit%2Fhow-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android%2F&docid=Rv_aBjoYtF0TvM&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Flondatiga.net%2Fimages%2Fquickactions%2Fquickcontact.jpg&w=200&h=300&ei=ykgUU--bJsiqhAfBj4DoBw&zoom=1&ved=0CFEQhBwwAA&iact=rc&dur=242&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom dialog.

Please check it out: https://github.com/MacoTasu/SGSelectViewController

Hope, It will may helpful to you,

:)